# Emacs lisp high-order function support

Tags: emacs, functional-programming, lisp, elisp

I am trying to implement Haskell-like high-order function in Elisp, using closures.

```
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
(defun foo (pair)
    (car pair))
(defun* .curry (fn)
    (lambda (x y &rest args) (apply fn (cons x y) args)))

((lambda (x y) (1+ x)) 2 3)
((lambda (&rest args) (apply (.curry #'foo) args)) 2 3)
(funcall (.curry #'foo) 2 3)
((.curry #'foo) 2 3)
```

Problem is that last line returns error `Invalid function`. So, it seems closure do not considered sane function. I still can use `(.curry #'foo)` in `mapc`, but not in hooks.
Is it something I can do about it?

Comment: Rewrite `.curry` as a macro? That is idea! Thanks for all this information!

Answer (score 2):

Your `((.curry #'foo) 2 3)` is invalid in any Lisp I know of except Scheme (and Scheme derivatives such as Racket).  The simplest code that illustrates the issue is as follows:

```
(defun f () (lambda ()))
(funcall (f)) ; tested in Emacs 23 and CLISP, works
((f)) ; tested in Emacs 23 and CLISP, results in an error
```